# Resizing the stage and camera

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-screen-support

I have a problem with my resizing method in libgdx, when I ran my game on my phone all works fine, but when I ran the game in another phone which is more bigger all is getting smaller and it just look bad.

Here is my resizing method:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    ...

    camera.viewportHeight = height /  1.1f;
    camera.viewportWidth = width / 1.1f;



    stage.setViewport(width, height, true);

        table.invalidateHierarchy();
        table.setSize(width, height);
        table2.invalidateHierarchy();
        table2.setSize(width, height);
        table3.invalidateHierarchy(); 
        table3.setSize(width, height);
        table4.invalidateHierarchy();
        table4.setSize(width, height);

}
```

And this method just give a bad effect.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What if you add `super.resize(width, height);`

Comment: There is no such a thing when I implementing the screen and not the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect question to introduce [`Viewport`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/package-summary.html), which has been added *today*.

Viewports are made especially to deal with this very problem. Have a look at [this news](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3322) and [the wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) to see how those work.

However, those are only available in the nightly build.

What you are actually doing at the moment, is implementing the "`ScreenViewport`" yourself, which always keeps the size of the screen, which leads to no stretching, but it will show more or less of your world.

What you are probably looking for, is `FitViewport` or maybe `StretchViewport`. Those offer you a *virtual* screen size and will scale this to fit your screen.

Comment: thank you very much. And sorry for my poor english .

Comment: Hi. Viewport will manage the camera for you. Camera actually has no clue about the viewport. Do `viewport = new FitViewport(cam, 80, 45)` and update only the viewport. Also use `Viewport.unproject` to do picking, don't use `Camera.unproject` anymore, and let viewport care about `Camera.viewportWidth/Height` for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! And now I have more one little question, from where can I download the latest release? and how I updating my existing project?

Comment: here http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html you can download both the latest release and the nightly build. The Viewport is only available in the nightly build. If you used the gdx-setup-ui (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-setup%2C-running-%26-debugging) for creating your projects, it also has an "Update" mode. In case you didn't use that, you have to manually replace all jars. For the future, please don't ask questions in the comments, but rather create a new question. It will also help others to find the answers, if they have the same questions.